# PHP preg_match: How is this passing of a variable to preg_match working?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This finds what it is supposed to:

```
if(!preg_match($match="/^http\/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+[ \t]*(.*)\$/i",$line,$matches))
```

But this does not:

```
if(!preg_match("/^http\/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+[ \t]*(.*)\$/i",$line,$matches))
```

The function reference for preg_match says that the first argument passed should be:

> The pattern to search for, as a
>   string.

But the working example I give above assigns the pattern to a variable: `$match=...`

What is going on here? I have never seen a variable used with preg_match like that. I thought it should be:

```
preg_match(string $regexpattern, string $thingtosearch, array $matches)
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: What if you assign first then do `if (!preg_match($match, $line, $matches))`? All these cases should yield the same result because it shouldn't matter as long as you pass in a valid pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example saves the pattern to a local variable.

```
if(!preg_match($match="/^http\/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+[ \t]*(.*)\$/i",$line,$matches))
```

It is equivalent to writing it like that:

```
$match="/^http\/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+[ \t]+[ \t]*(.*)\$/i";   
if(!preg_match($match,$line,$matches))
```

The preg_match function doesn't "see" that the parameter was assigned to a variable, it only ever receives the value - because there are no named function parameters in PHP. It's hence unimportant how you name the local variables, and the $param definition in the manual has zero influence over functionality.

A probable explanation for this code structure is that the regex pattern `$match` might be reused later on. Sometimes this notation is just used for readability. (It's garbaging up the local variable scope, yet adds some minor clarity.)

Answer (score 2):

An [assignment expression](http://php.net/language.operators.assignment) returns the value that was assigned. So in your case the assignment expression `$match="…"` returns the assigned value `"…"` that results in the same parameter for the function as without that assignment.

Doing it that way is useful in some cases like in a condition of `while`:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Here `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` returns the same value that was returned by `mysql_fetch_array($result)` but it’s also assigned to `$row`.